# Converting sample List with repeating measurements into Dataframe

Tags: r

I'm quite new to R and try to tackle the following problem. I have a list that looks like this:

```
head(r1.zonalstats)
[[1]]
    count min max range     mean       sd     sum median
1 1348692 -86  62   148 2.981043 21.67855 4020509      2

[[2]]
   count  min max range     mean       sd       sum median
1 901011 -173 239   412 116.2252 76.43403 104720166    128

[[3]]
    count min max range     mean       sd       sum median
1 1556708  72 233   161 176.5539 27.95961 274842944    169

[[4]]
    count min max range    mean       sd       sum median
1 1279441 -86 160   246 95.7123 31.84009 122458239     94
.
..
...
```

I'd like to convert it into a data.frame-object with count, min, max and so on in the first column and all the values in the subsequent columns. Something like this:

```
number  count    min  max  range      mean        sd        sum  median
     1  1348692  -86   62    148  2.981043  21.67855    4020509       2
     2   901011 -173  239    412  116.2252  76.43403  104720116     128
     3  1556708   72  233    161  176.5539  27.95961  274842944     169
...
```

Has anyone an idea, how to do this?

Comment: `do.call(rbind,r1.zonalstats)`

Comment: or `do.call(rbind.data.frame, r1.zonalstats)` if you want to make sure that you get a data.frame and not a matrix.

Comment: Wow...how easy was that!? ^^ Thank you!